# How to add a row to a table using swt

Tags: java, swt

I am learning swing and have one doubt regarding insertion of row to a table.
My requirement is such that I have to add a new row by pressing a add button. But I am not able to proceed. please find the code below:

If some one know please help me....

```
{public class TableShellExample {


Display d;
 Shell s;
 TableViewer tableViewer;
 CellEditor cellEditor;

 TableShellExample(){
  d = new Display();
  s = new Shell();
  s.setSize(250,250);
  s.setText("Table Shell Example");

  GridLayout g1 = new GridLayout();
  g1.numColumns = 3;
  s.setLayout(g1);
  final Table table = new Table(s,SWT.BORDER |SWT.CHECK|SWT.MULTI | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
  GridData gd = new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH);
  gd.horizontalSpan = 3;
  table.setLayoutData(gd);
  table.setHeaderVisible(true);

  TableColumn tc1 = new TableColumn(table, SWT.LEFT);
  TableColumn tc2 = new TableColumn(table,SWT.CENTER);
  TableColumn tc3 = new TableColumn(table,SWT.CENTER);
  tc1.setText("FIRST NAME");
  tc2.setText("LAST NAME");
  tc3.setText("ADDRESS");
  tc1.setWidth(70);
     tc2.setWidth(70);
     tc3.setWidth(80);
  TableItem it1 = new TableItem(table,SWT.NONE);
  it1.setText(new String[]{"aaa","bbb","pune"});
  TableItem it2 = new TableItem(table,SWT.NONE);
  it2.setText(new String[]{"aaa","bbb","pune"});
  TableItem it3 = new TableItem(table,SWT.NONE);
  it3.setText(new String[]{"aaa","bbb","pune"});

  //tableViewer = new TableViewer(table);
  //tableViewer.setColumnProperties(tc1);
  //tableViewer.setContentProvider(new IContentProvider());
  //tableViewer.setLabelProvider(new TableLabelProvider());

  CellEditor[] editors = new CellEditor[2];
  //editors[0] = new TextCellEditor(table);
  //editors[1] = new TextCellEditor(table);
  //tableViewer.setCellEditors(editors);
  //tableViewer.setCellModifier(new ICellModifier());


  final Text input = new Text(s, SWT.SINGLE | SWT.BORDER);
     input.setTextLimit(5);
     final Button searchBtn = new Button(s, SWT.BORDER | SWT.PUSH);
     searchBtn.setText("Search");
  searchBtn.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
  public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e){
   TableItem[] tia = table.getItems();
   for(int i=0;i<tia.length;i++){
    tia[i].getText();
     //tia[i].setBackground(new Color(d, 129, 178, 127));
    //}


   }
  }

  });
  final Button addButton = new Button(s,SWT.BORDER | SWT.PUSH);
  addButton.setText("Add Row");
  addButton.setToolTipText("for addind a new row");
  addButton.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {

   public void handleEvent(Event arg0) {
    TableEditor te = new TableEditor(table);
    te.grabHorizontal = true;
    te.grabVertical = true;
    te.getItem();
    TableItem ti = table.getItem(0);
    ti.getText();


   }
  });
  s.open();
     while (!s.isDisposed()) {
       if (!d.readAndDispatch())
         d.sleep();
     }
     d.dispose();
 }
 public Vector rowToAdd() {
  Vector defaultRow = new Vector();
  defaultRow.add("column1");
  defaultRow.add("column1");
  return defaultRow;
  }

 public static void main(String[] argv){
  new TableShellExample();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Here's a simple working example of how to add items to a table when a button is pressed:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    RowLayout layout = new RowLayout(SWT.VERTICAL);
    layout.fill = true;
    shell.setLayout(layout);
    shell.setSize(200, 200);
    final Table table = new Table(shell, SWT.BORDER | SWT.MULTI);
    final Text text = new Text(shell, SWT.SINGLE | SWT.BORDER);
    text.setText("blahblah text");
    Button button = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
    button.setText("Push me");

    // this is the code you want
    button.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            TableItem item = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
            item.setText(text.getText());
        }
    });

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        TableItem item = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
        item.setText("*** Item " + i + "***");
    }
    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

If you must use the TableViewer system to add items, you need to modify whatever Object is passed into the viewer as its input. If you use an `IStructuredContentProvider` as your viewer's content provider, the `getElements` method returns an array that goes on to become your table's rows. To update it after a change to the input, just call `viewer.refresh()`

Comment: Thank a lot Dylan Halperin for your reply

Answer (score 1):

> **Easy way for learning** :Text field record add in Table and selected row
>   can display on text field using SWT

---

```
package rcp_demo.Views;

import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;

public class TaskView extends ViewPart {

    public static Table table;
    public static TableViewer tableViewer;
    public static TableItem std_item;
    private  Text txt_1,txt_2,txt_3;

    Student stud=new Student();
    List<Student> std=new ArrayList<Student>();

    public TaskView() {
        setTitleImage(SWTResourceManager.getImage("D:\\Icon\\Tasksview.png"));
    }

    @Override
    public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
        parent.setLayout(null);
        //Three Text
        txt_1 = new Text(parent, SWT.BORDER);
        txt_1.setBounds(21, 10, 76, 19);

        txt_2 = new Text(parent, SWT.BORDER);
        txt_2.setBounds(119, 10, 76, 19);

        txt_3 = new Text(parent, SWT.BORDER);
        txt_3.setBounds(222, 10, 76, 19);

        tableViewer = new TableViewer(parent, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
        table = tableViewer.getTable();

        //how to pass values of a selected row from tableviewer to a text box in SWT

         table.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener()
            {
                @Override
                public void handleEvent(Event e) {
                     Table table = (Table) e.widget;
                        TableItem item = table.getItem(table.getSelectionIndex());

                        /* Fill the texts */
                        for (int col = 0; col < table.getColumnCount(); col++)
                        {
                            if(col==0)
                            {
                                txt_1.setText(item.getText(col));
                            }
                            else if(col==1)
                            {
                                txt_2.setText(item.getText(col));
                            }
                            else if(col==2)
                            {
                                txt_3.setText(item.getText(col));
                            }
                        }
                }
            });
        table.setBounds(21, 47, 290, 213);
        table.setHeaderVisible(true);
        table.setLinesVisible(true);

        //ADD Button

        Button btnAdd = new Button(parent, SWT.NONE);
        btnAdd.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {

                std.add(new Student(txt_1.getText(),txt_2.getText(),txt_3.getText()));
                std_item=new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
                std_item.setText(0,txt_1.getText());
                std_item.setText(1,txt_2.getText());
                std_item.setText(2,txt_3.getText());

            }
        });
        btnAdd.setBounds(304, 10, 68, 23);
        btnAdd.setText("Add");

                //Dynamic add column Name using TableViewerColumn 

                String[] Col_names={"Stud_id","Stud_Name","Stud_Gender"};
                for(int i=0;i<Col_names.length;i++)
                {
                    TableViewerColumn tableViewerColumn = new TableViewerColumn(tableViewer, SWT.NONE);
                    TableColumn tblclmnNewColumn = tableViewerColumn.getColumn();
                    tblclmnNewColumn.setWidth(100);
                    tblclmnNewColumn.setText(Col_names[i]);

                }
                //(class: Student)static Item/Data Add

                std.add(new Student("110","Deni","Male"));
                std.add(new Student("111","Hina","Female"));
                std.add(new Student("112","Jem","Male"));


                for(Student s:std)
                {
                    TableItem std_item=new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
                    std_item.setText(0,s.getStd_id());
                    std_item.setText(1,s.getStd_nm());
                    std_item.setText(2,s.getStd_gender());
                }

    }
      public TableViewer getViewer() {
          return tableViewer;
  }
    @Override
    public void setFocus() {
        tableViewer.getControl().setFocus();

    }
}
```

---

> Class name : Student.java

---

```
package rcp_demo.TableView;

public class Student {

private String std_id;
private String std_nm;
private String std_gender;

public Student() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
public Student(String sid,String snm,String sgender) {
    std_id=sid;
    std_nm=snm;
    std_gender=sgender;
}

public String getStd_id() {
    return std_id;
}
public void setStd_id(String std_id) {
    this.std_id = std_id;
}
public String getStd_nm() {
    return std_nm;
}
public void setStd_nm(String std_nm) {
    this.std_nm = std_nm;
}
public String getStd_gender() {
    return std_gender;
}
public void setStd_gender(String std_gender) {
    this.std_gender = std_gender;
}

}
```