# Add rows to interface via button

Tags: java, swt

I'd like to build an interface to house settings for an application. After reading various guides I'm unsure what's the best way to build this, I'm primarily interested in a high level overview how to achieve that - sample code would help but isn't necessary. I looked into a table but that doesn't seem like the best way to do this from what I could find.

Here's a rough sketch on how I want it to look like:

[image: sketch-interface]

Usage: If you click on "Add version" a new row will be added.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think a `JTable` is not a good option?

Comment: You can try visual swing tool such as Window Builder in eclipse, and off-course netbeans has all what you want. You can use **JSplitPane**

Comment: SWT or Swing? Which one is it you want?

Comment: Sorry. SWT - I deleted the wrong tag.

Comment: I figured out how to do it with `JTable`. It seems like despite what I read before this is a possible way for that. For future reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665573/how-to-add-a-row-to-a-table-using-swt - Thanks!